# Why honest function example in C# still not being honest?

Tags: c#, functional-programming

from this reference : http://functionalprogrammingcsharp.com/honest-functions

I have learned to be more honest when defining method/function in C#.
It said that prefer pure function so that the function will always give the exact return type given in signature.

However when I try to apply it:

```
int Divide(int x, int y)
{
    return x / y;
}
```

From the website:

> The signature states that the function accepts two integers and returns another integer. But this is not the case in all scenarios. What happens if we invoke the function like Divide(1, 0)? The function implementation doesn't abide by its signature, throwing DivideByZero exception. That means this function is also "dishonest". How can we make this function an honest one? We can change the type of the y parameter (NonZeroInteger is a custom type which can contain any integer except zero):

```
int Divide(int x, NonZeroInteger y)
{
    return x / y.Value;
}
```

I'm not sure what is the implementation of NonZeroInteger, they don't seem to give any implementation of NonZeroInteger in the website, should it check for 0 inside that class? And
I'm pretty sure if I call Divide(1, null) it will still show an error, thus making the function not honest.

Why honest function example in C# still not being honest?

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a language barrier, but as far as I know, "honest" is not a technical term and I am not able to infer any specific meaning from your use of the word in this context. Can you try to describe the problem with technical and objective wording?

Comment: I've read the link and I think the author has bee a bit lazy by just throwing a `NonZeroInteger` type out there without any details.

Comment: Surely if you add the caveat "any function may throw an exception" then your function becomes "honest". After all, functions can fail for all manner of reasons beyond your control.

Comment: @JohnWu it's explained in the linked site pretty well. Essentially just means that methods should be totally transparent with regards to input and output.

Comment: @JohnWu I have updated my question, thank you, there seems to be language barrier

Comment: I really don't see the point to adhering to this in such a strict sense. Obviously there is a benefit to being "honest" to an extent, but if you're tracking down every possible "dishonest" possibility (which isn't really possible IMO), you're wasting *a lot* of time that could be spent on better things. Not to mention you're just pushing the possibility elsewhere (i.e. How will the implementation of `NonZeroInteger` now handle a 0?)

Comment: @BrootsWaymb I'm pretty sure the website article means honesty is to be bug free, to an extend of not wasting a lot of time spent on bug fixing.. I could spend time on better things

Comment: Presumably there would need to be some sort of "CreateNonZeroIntegerOrThrowExceptionIfZero" factory method to be 100% honest, but then like @BrootsWaymb said.. what's the point? You're just pushing off responsibility to a degree that seems to outweigh the benefit.

Comment: You could just invert this a bit and have a method: `bool TryDivide(int x, int y, out int result)` that avoids having to create a type.

Comment: @KevinTanudjaja - Any reasonably sizable app is not going to be bug free. That's a fantasy with regards to complexity beyond a "Hello World" type of app. This added complexity just to be "honest" seems like a possibility to introduce *more* bugs, or at the very least, some headaches and extra work. This practice is nice where reasonable, but don't treat it like the law/bible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taking the example you've posted, and having read the link, if you want to make the function "honest" then you don't really need to create a new type, you could just implement the `Try` pattern:

```
bool TryDivide(int x, int y, out int result)
{
  if(y != 0)
  {
    result = x / y;
    return true;
  }

  result = 0;
  return false;
}
```

This function basically fulfills the "honest" principle. The name says it will try to do division, and the resulting 'bool` says that it will indicate it is was successful.

You could create a `struct NonZeroInteger` but you're going to have to write a lot of code around it to make it act like a regular numeric type, and you'll probably come full circle. For example, what if you pass `0` to the `NonZeroInteger` constructor? Should it fail? Is that honest.

Also, `struct` type always have a default constructor, so if you're wrapping an `int` it's going to be awkward to avoid it being set to 0.

Comment: Yes, you could create a get property, that never returns 0, but definitely awkward.

Comment: @Pac0 - but that would just mean that the property isn't "honest"!

Answer (score 2):

The notion of "honest function" still has room for interpretation, and I don't want to debate about it here, would be more opinion than actual useful answer.

To specifically answer your example, you could declare `NonZeroInteger` as a ValueType, with `struct` instead of `class`.

A value type is non-nullable (except if you explicitly specify the nullable version with a `?`). No null-problem in this case. By the way, `int` is an example of value type (it's an alias for `System.Int32`, to be exact).

As some have [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61015597/479251), it could lead to other difficulties (struct has always a default constructor that initialize all fields to their default, and the default for an `int` is 0...)

For an mid-experienced programmer, this kind of example does not need to be explicitly implemented in the article to be understood on principle.

However, if you are unsure about it, it would definitely be a good programming learning exercise, I strongly encourage you to implement it yourself! (And create unit tests to demonstrate that your function has no "bug", by the way)

Comment: Even if I make it a struct, create constructor to not allow 0 values, i'm still need to provide a way how to handle if it's divided by 0, it's basically saying to return 0 if divided by 0

Comment: @KevinTanudjaja : I was trying to focus on the "NonZeroInteger". Here, you can define a public property, backed by a private `int` field. In the `get`ter of the property, just return another random value (1 for instance) in case the field is zero. It's ugly, I don't recommend it, but it fits the requirements of never returning zero, _and_ also to avoid any `null`.

Answer (score 2):

To make it honest, define a new data structure and check the status.

```
enum Status { OK, NAN }
class Data
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public Status Status { get; set; }

    public static Data operator /(Data l, Data r)
    {
        if (r.Value == 0)
        {
            // Value  can be set to any number, here I choose 0. 
            return new Data { Value = 0, Status = Status.NAN };
        }
        return new Data { Value = l.Value / r.Value, Status = Status.OK };
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"Value: {Value}, Status: {Enum.GetName(Status.GetType(), Status)}";
    }
}

class Test
{
    static Data Divide(Data left, Data right)
    {
        return left / right;
    }
    static void Main()
    {
        Data left = new Data { Value = 1 };
        Data right = new Data { Value = 0 };
        Data output = Divide(left, right);

        Console.WriteLine(output);
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, I think it's either TryGetValue answer above, or create new Data Structure, or make Tuples!

Answer (score 1):

This `NonZeroInteger` is just a "symbol", which just represents the idea, not conrete implementation.

Surely, author could provide implemenetation of such construct, but its name servers just right for the sake of an article.

Possible implememntation might be:

```
public class NonZeroInteger
{
  public int Value { get; set; }
  public NonZeroInteger(int value)
  {
    if( value == 0 ) throw new ArgumentException("Argument passed is zero!");
    Value = value;
  }
}
```

But it's just pushing dishonesty somewhere else (in terms of an article), because constructor should return an object, not throw exception.

IMO, honesty is not achievable, because it's just moving dishonesty somewhere else, as shown in this example.

Comment: That's not going to work.  All `structs` come with a built in default constructor (that you cannot change).  The default constructor will set all members to their default value.  As a result, the backing field for the `Value` property will be set to zero.  I suspect that if you made an immutable class (like `System.String`), you might come close, but you'd loose value type semantics (for example, an array of `NonZeroInteger` instances would have all the array items set to `null` on initialization).  There's pretty much no way to do this that I can think of

Comment: yep, nice catch about the default constructor @Flydog57 . It's more complicated that it looks...

Comment: Oh well.. I also believe the article NonZeroInteger is not achievable.

Comment: @KevinTanudjaja it is achievable. For isntance, you could expose the value only through a property, and make sure the getter of the property never returns 0... but it would be definitely more helpful for the programmer if the data structure here was not trying to "hide the problem", throwing an exception instead. And hiding the truth / problem is precisely the opposite of the meaning of the _honest_ word in English!

Answer (score 0):

After reading it thoroughly a lot of times..

I found that his second option on the website is honest, and the first one is wrong.

```
int? Divide(int x, int y)
    {
        if (y == 0)
        return null;
        return x / y;
    }
```

Edit: got idea from another article, basically mimicking the F# path, something like this:

```
Option<int> Divide(int x, int y)
    {
        if (y == 0)
            return Option<int>.CreateEmpty();
        return Option<int>.Create(x / y);
    }

public class Option<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    private readonly T[] _data;

    private Option(T[] data)
    {
        _data = data;
    }

    public static Option<T> Create(T element)
    {
        return new Option<T>(new T[] { element });
    }

    public static Option<T> CreateEmpty()
    {
        return new Option<T>(new T[0]);
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return ((IEnumerable<T>) _data).GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    public void Match(Action<T> onSuccess, Action onError) {
        if(_data.Length == 0) {
            onError();
        } else {
            onSuccess(_data[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

Ref: https://www.matheus.ro/2017/09/26/design-patterns-and-practices-in-net-option-functional-type-in-csharp/

to call:

```
public void Main() {
    Option<int> result = Divide(1,0);
    result.Match(
        x => Console.Log(x),
        () => Console.Log("divided by zero")
    )
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is "honest". Using `null` as a magic value is a bit of a hack.

Comment: Yeah, that's dishonest :)

Comment: This article treats nulls inconsistently. In the first example, a null is "bad" although a string can be null. A null string is still a string. Later a nullable int returning null is legitimate though. Like @Sean said, it's a hack here, just like the author themselves consider it a hack with a string. I don't see why it should be treated differently.

Comment: Your option class won't work if `null` is a valid value for some operation.

Comment: @Sean you mean passing null value around method?

Comment: @KevinTanudjaja - What I mean if you've picked `null` as a magic value. It isn't applicable it `T` is a value type so `if(Value == null)` will always be `false`. For reference types it may be the case that `Some(null)` is a valid answer, but your code assumes `null` means `None`

Comment: @KevinTanudjaja - You code calls `Option.Some(x / y)` and `Option.None` but that isn't valid as you've missed off the generic type.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to mention that `NonZeroInteger` can definitely be implemented honestly using a variation on [Peano numbers](https://wiki.haskell.org/Peano_numbers):

```cs
class NonZeroInteger
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a non-zero integer with the given value.
    /// (This is private, so you don't have to worry about
    /// anyone passing in 0.)
    /// </summary>
    private NonZeroInteger(int value)
    {
        _value = value;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Value of this instance as plain integer.
    /// </summary>
    public int Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
    }
    private readonly int _value;

    public static NonZeroInteger PositiveOne = new NonZeroInteger(1);
    public static NonZeroInteger NegativeOne = new NonZeroInteger(-1);

    /// <summary>
    /// Answers a new non-zero integer with a magnitude that is
    /// one greater than this instance.
    /// </summary>
    public NonZeroInteger Increment()
    {
        var newValue = _value > 0
            ? _value + 1    // positive number gets more positive
            : _value - 1;   // negative number gets more negative
        return new NonZeroInteger(newValue);   // can never be 0
    }
}
```

The only tricky part is that I've defined `Increment` so that it works with both positive and negative integers. You can create any integer value you want except zero, and no exceptions are ever thrown, so this class is totally honest. (I'm ignoring overflow for now, but I don't think it would be a problem.)

Yes, it requires you to increment by one repeatedly to build large integers, which is extremely inefficient, but that's OK for a toy class like this one. There are probably other honest implementations that would be more efficient (e.g. using a `uint` as an offset from +1 or -1), but I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader.

You can test it like this:

```cs
class Test
{
    static int Divide(int x, NonZeroInteger y)
    {
        return x / y.Value;
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        var posThree = NonZeroInteger.PositiveOne
            .Increment()
            .Increment();
        Console.WriteLine(Divide(7, posThree));

        var negThree = NonZeroInteger.NegativeOne
            .Increment()
            .Increment();
        Console.WriteLine(Divide(7, negThree));
    }
}
```

Output is:

```
2
-2
```

Answer (score -1):

Honestly this is, IMO, overkill, but if I were to do a "Honest" method. I would do something like this. Instead of creating an entire new class. This is not a recommendation of what to do, and could easily cause issues in your code later. The best way to handle this, IMO, is to use the function and catch the exception outside of the Method. This is an "Honest" method in the fact that it always returns an integer, but it could return false values back.

```
    int Divide(int x, int y)
    {
        try
        {
            return x / y;
        }
        catch (DivideByZeroException)
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I wouldn't say this is honest at all. Not only is it totally mathematically incorrect to return 0 if you divide by zero, it masks possible errors elsewhere in the code (what if this method should never be passed a zero? Well, now you can't tell anything went wrong).

Comment: Why not just check so see if `y` is zero in the first place?

Comment: Really? So the fact that division of 2 integers will never equal 0 isn't a dead giveaway.

Comment: This is a valid answer. It is "Honest" in the terms that it always returns an int.

Comment: @PatrickMcvay - Umm... what if x is zero? It's trivial to get division to equal zero legitimately.

Comment: It would still throw a divide by 0 exception.

Comment: or well equal 0

Comment: It's not a mathematical problem here, the fact that it is wrong mathematically and causes issues, bugs later in the code because of some false assumptions is independent from the fact that this function is "honest" in the sense that it doesn't throws. And by the way, it's a good example to show that "honesty" is either ill-defined or is not a silver bullet _at all_

Comment: Either way it goes. I do understand that this is horrible to put in your code. I am not arguing that point.